# Is there any function to remove all of the tailwind css classes remove from NextJs app?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js, tailwind-css

We are in big project like amazon. So,two branches use bootstrap 4. Now in main branch we are install tailwind css and i also added content path in  tailwind.config.js. it's work perfectly...
But the problem is now getting some overwritten bootstrap by the tailwind classes...
*When i remove @tailwind base, components, utilities from the global.css then bootstrap work fine. But after added those line then again bootstrap not working and it's come some tailwind classes.*

**So, now how can i fix it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [prefix](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) all tailwind CSS classes to remove naming conflicts.

*tailwind.config.js*

```js
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

You will need to update your classes in your codebase to reflect the prefix.

For example - `<div className="flex">` would now be `<div className="tw-flex">`

Prefixes are only added to default tailwind classes.  You need to manually prefix any custom classes or change their names to prevent conflicts with other frameworks.

---

Tailwind has some base styles that you can omit by disabling [preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight).

*tailwind.config.js*

```js
corePlugins: {
  preflight: false,
}
```

Comment: It's fine....But even then it doesn't work ..h1,h2,h3 this types of element getting tallwind style not bootstrap so, there are any way to stop the style going in every components? I also use the tailwind.config.js content path... it's work...but Even then my previous tailwind will style apply that's i don't want..

Comment: Import bootstrap after tailwind in your _app file and disable preflight. See the updated post.  Tailwind doesn't style heading - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#headings-are-unstyled - Idk your structure, so it's hard to tell.  If the style is imported globally it will apply to all components in that app with matching classes/elements.

Comment: hmmm I was found it yesterday...thanks